# Как добавить ScrollView в уже созданную разметку

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-scrollview

Есть разметка вида:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context="ru.mail.xaxa.InndexActivity" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#2196f3" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />




<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="145dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/lenin" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="145dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/dedchit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Как мне сюда добавить ScrollView ? Пытался это все обернуть в него но ничего не вышло.
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6674341

Comment: Что значит "Не вышло"? Какие были проблемы? Код не копипастился? =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб был вылет из приложения. сделал как указано в ответах по ссылке пользователя pavlofff, но получилось что и toolBarr скролится ....

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос (обязательно!) что был вылет и прикрепите StackTrace ошибки из logCat (тоже обязательно!). И делайте так всегда для каждого вопроса. А скроллится тулбар, т.к. скроллВью всё в себе скролит.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я кажется понял в чем проблема. спасибо. я учту все

Comment: Если проблему решили-распишите подробно в ответе-это может многим пригодится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context="ru.mail.xaxa.InndexActivity" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#2196f3" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="145dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/lenin" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="145dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/dedchit" />

</RelativeLayout>    
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```